# What are the rules or laws a Catholic must follow if he/she has a website or blog?

Tags: catholicism, canon-law, internet

Are there any rules or laws (of the Code of Canon Law) that a Catholic must adhere to if he/she operates a blog or website in which he may teach or write about the Catholic faith?

Comment: How about canon law?

Comment: @DoubleU I rather think that that's what the question is asking about!

Comment: Not an answer but I would very much doubt that fundamentally the rules for blogging are any different from the rules for broadcasting, lecturing, or writing of any other kind.

Comment: Related: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35311/what-issues-do-catholics-representing-god-in-fiction-historically-face

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code of Canon Law, Book III *The Teaching Function of the Church*

> The Church, to which Christ the Lord has entrusted the **deposit of
>   faith** so that with the assistance of the Holy Spirit it might protect
>   the revealed truth reverently, examine it more closely, and proclaim
>   and expound it faithfully, has the duty and innate right, independent
>   of any human power whatsoever, to preach the gospel to all peoples,
>   also using the means of **social communication** proper to it. ([Can. 747 §1](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P2H.HTM), *emphases mine*)

I think that about covers it.

(There's also quite a bit about publishing in [Title IV](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P2Q.HTM) *Instruments of Social Communication and Books in Particular*.)